# One to one chat in Atmosphere java

Tags: java, dropwizard, atmosphere

I was able to find a couple of examples for broadcasting messages with Atmosphere framework in Java but couldn't find any concrete example for one to one chat. I would like to deliver messages to particular users for which it will be intended for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Broadcaster#broadcast(Object, AtmosphereResource)](http://atmosphere.github.io/atmosphere/apidocs/org/atmosphere/cpr/Broadcaster.html#broadcast%28java.lang.Object,%20org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource%29) to deliver a message to a specific connection.